# LogisticRegression (sklearn) - why does 'predict_proba' yield better results?

Tags: regression, scikit-learn

I'm practicing my machinelearning / sklearn skills with [a kaggle playground](https://www.kaggle.com/jasperkoops/logistic-model-with-pipeline) and I'm having trouble why a suggested change made by a fellow user yields better results.
The challenge involves binary classification and the results are ranked by their `roc_auc` score.

I created a classifier (`clf`) using LogisticRegression and made the predictions with the following line of code

`predictions = clf.predict(X)`

This method resulted in a score of 0.68.

A fellow user suggested that I instead used the following method:

`predictions = clf.predict_proba(X)[:,1]`

This did indeed result in a higher score (0.76), but I'm having trouble understanding why.

As I understand it, the `predict` method takes the highest scoring class of the `predict_proba` as its output and thus the score between both examples should be the same.

e.g:

```
prob_0 | prob_1 | predict

 0.3      0.7       1
 0.51     0.49      0
```

The higher score of the `predict_proba` method indicates that my understanding of these methods is flawed, but I'm not sure what I'm getting wrong here. Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your understanding of the method is correct. However, I find it weird that you can simply submit your probabilities [0,1] rather than actual class prediction {0,1}. Maybe it computes the AUC automatically within Kaggle for several threshold and reports the best one? Can you link the Kaggle discussion please.

Comment: Maybe you want to read how to calculate auc.  ( One view is basically sweeping decision threshold from zero to one). If you only provide preclassified values (ie zero and 1), then how do you do this...

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I received the tip in my kernel (https://www.kaggle.com/jasperkoops/logistic-model-with-pipeline), I've included the link in the original post as well. (It probably should have been there from the beginning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curve is computed by plotting the True Positive Rate (TPR) against the False Positive Rate (FPR) at uniformly distributed threshold values from 0 to 1. The Area Under the Curve (AUC) is then calculated to turn this into a numerical score.

This means that you need to provide a vector of probabilities in order for the various thresholds to be meaningful. SKlearn's `predict` function simply provides binary value based on a threshold of 0.5. This will be interpreted as a vector of probabilities that are either 0% or 100%, making any changes in the threshold value irrelevant.